# Cannot edit HAML files in carlhuda - janus VIM distro

Tags: vim, haml, janus

I switched from my own VIM setup to [janus](https://github.com/carlhuda/janus) recently. I really like the organization.

When I tried to edit and save HAML files, I got following error.

```
Error detected while processing function <SNR>44_UpdateErrors..<SNR>44_RefreshSigns..<SNR>44_SignErrors:
line   12:
E474: Invalid argument
```

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an error with **syntastic** plugin. I created an issue at [GitHub](https://github.com/carlhuda/janus/issues/210).

**[scrooloose](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic)** has fixed this issue. 
You can find the patch [here](https://github.com/scrooloose/syntastic/commit/17183c6d19b7d1ced18e18187eeb2fa148f1a29e)

Simply run

`rake`

inside your ~/.vim directory. It'll update the **syntastic** plugin.

Answer (score 0):

probably, it will fix with fixing following line in your vimrc.

```
let g:syntastic_enable_signs=1
```

to

```
let g:syntastic_enable_signs=0
```